# Unpack dictionary that contains a list of dictionaries and insert in columns

Tags: python, database, loops, dictionary, flask-sqlalchemy

With the data below, I'm trying to unfold a dictionary that contains a list of dictionaries, and then group each key with the corresponding values of the other dictionaries together. For example:

```
result = {
    'themes' : [{
            'a' : 'orange',
            'b' : 6,
            'c' : 'neutral',
            'd' : 6,
            'e' : 0.24
        }, {
            'a' : 'banana',
            'b' : 6,
            'c' : 'neutral',
            'd' : 6,
            'e' : 0.16
        }, {
            'a' : 'phone',
            'b' : 5,
            'c' : 'neutral',
            'd' : 5,
            'e' : 0.02
        }
    ]
}
```

...should become something along these lines:

```
themes={'a' : ['orange','banana', 'phone']}

count={'b' : [6,6,5]}

s_score={'c' : [neutral, neutral, neutral]}
```

...and so on.

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485247/dictionary-that-contains-list), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421906/how-to-merge-lists-of-dictionaries), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression) among other places, but couldn't find something close enough to what I want to do. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972204/combine-dictionary-entries-by-common-elements) came pretty close, but it's checking for at least one or more common values, whereas mine should group common keys. I know I can separate the outer key from the values like this:

```
>>>(k, v), = result.items()
>>>k
>>>'themes'
>>>v
>>>[{
        'a' : 'orange',
        'b :6,
        'c' : 'neutral',
        'd' : 6,
        'e' : 0.24
    }, {
        'a' : 'banana',
        'b' : 6,
        'c' : 'neutral',
        'd' : 6,
        'e' : 0.16
    }, {
        'a' : 'phone',
        'b' : 5,
        'c' : 'neutral',
        'd' : 5,
        'e' : 0.02
    }
]
```

but how do I get the v list of dictionaries to the way I described? Do I have to convert them to sets first?

To make my intention clear, my ultimate goal is iterate through the list of values of the keys that I want to keep, so I can enter them into their respective columns in my fairly basic flask-sqlalchemy SQLite database. So in the end I'll be able to query and get them displayed as html:

```
+-----------------+----------+----------+-------+
|       a         |    b     |    c     |   d   |
+-----------------+----------+----------+-------+
|     orange      |   2.4    | neutral  |   6   |
|     banana      |   1.6    | neutral  |   6   |
+-----------------+----------+----------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict1 = {}
for eachKey in list(set(",".join(each.keys()) for each in result["themes"]))[0].split(","):
    dict1[eachKey] = [each[eachKey] for each in result["themes"]]
print dict1
```

It will reduce your `result` to following dictionary-

```
{'a': ['orange', 'banana', 'phone'], 'c': ['neutral', 'neutral', 'neutral'], 'b': ['6', 6, 5], 'e': [0.24, 0.16, 0.02], 'd': [6, 6, 5]}
```

Comment: Your code and Saksham 's code worked great, thanks! I'm using the former. ipoteka 's solution also worked, but for some reason, when I had a larger number of dictionary items, it was also giving me the original format at the first element.

Answer (score 0):

You should first flatMap all your values in the list of tuples (`[('a', 'orange'), ('c', 'neutral'), ('b', '6')`..]) and then groupBy first element. I would do it this way:

```
import itertools

pairs =  itertools.chain.from_iterable([d.items() for d in result["themes"]])
result = {}
for key, elem in pairs:
    result.setdefault(key, []).append(elem)
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for i,j in result.iteritems():
    for k in j:
        for l,m in k.iteritems():
            d[l].append(m)
>>>d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': ['orange', 'banana', 'phone'], 'c': ['neutral', 'neutral', 'neutral'], 'b': ['6', 6, 5], 'e': [0.24, 0.16, 0.02], 'd': [6, 6, 5]})
```

Now you can parse it by

```
themes = {'a':d['a']}    
>>>themes
{'a': ['orange', 'banana', 'phone']}
```

And so on.Hope this helps

Comment: Looks good, but I haven't gotten this to work yet because I'm using Python 3, which doesn't support dict.iteritems()

Comment: so you can use `dict.items()`

Answer (score 0):

You can keep `themes`, `count` and `score` in one dictionary -- `final_dict`.
In code:

```
>>> lst = result['themes']
>>> final_dict = {}

>>> for d in lst:
...    for (k, v) in d.items():
...        final_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
>>> print final_dict

{'a': ['orange', 'banana', 'phone'], 'c': ['neutral', 'neutral', 'neutral'], 'b': [6, 6, 5], 'e': [0.24, 0.16, 0.02], 'd': [6, 6, 5]}
```